# Twilio Tracking System in Python

Tags: python, twilio

I'm trying to use Twilio so that users can send an SMS with a different tracking code based on their item, and the Twilio mobile number will respond with a list of the names and locations of everyone who has entered that number before. If the item hasn't been tracked before (nobody has texted that code before), it'll respond with "This pad hasn't been tracked."

I understand that this is a key word application, and I'm trying to implement it in Python. However even after looking at the online Twilio Python API and their other resources, I'm still confused about how to write the appropriate code. Thanks in advance to everyone!

Answer (score 4):

Well, you'd do better to use Python/Django, but here goes (in Python Django):

First, you buy a Twilio Number.  In the number you purchase, are a couple of fields, one of which is for incoming SMS messages.  You need to set a url there, that Twilio will hit when the device sends the SMS to the number (initially, it goes to a Demo link).  The url that will be hit is on YOUR server. 
So, you set up the url route so that it gets called when Twilio hits the url.  Then, you write some code in Python to read the request variables, like this:

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
from twilio import twiml  # Get these as pip packages from Twilio

def hello(request):  # This is the script that the url hits
    from_num = request.POST.get("From", None)  # The callers number, if known, in e164 format.
    our_num = request.POST.get("To", None)  # The twilio number called, in e164 format.
    SID = request.POST.get("MessagingServiceSid", None)  # The first part of the key 
    AccountSID = request.POST.get("AccountSid", None) # the second part of the key.
    key = "%s%s" % (SID, AccountSID)
    message_body = request.POST.get("Body", None) # Get the actual text that was sent.
    r = twiml.Response() # This allows the server to respond with the Twilio scripting language, twiml.
    ~~~~~~
    Do Parsing stuff here, and get the list to respond with as variable "body"
    ~~~~~~
    r.message(body) # This sends back your list as a text message to the sender.
    return str(r)  # Send the completed response to Twilio for forwarding.
```

It's pretty much that easy.  What gets extremely complicated is watching for blocked numbers, catching errors, bad utf-8 text conversions, all that.

[Link to Twilio docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message)

Also, be advised, EVERY 160 characters is a message, and messages over 160 characters are broken up and charged per message.  So, either keep the messages less than 160, or be prepared to pay the extra cost.

Comment: How do I create the url and add my Python code? I just have my code in an IDE right now

Comment: You have to have a web server of some sort, that can respond to HTTP requests.  Otherwise, you can only create a timed function, and use their messaging service REST API to get the messages every so often.  The issue with doing that, is that the user does not get an instant response.
There are many tutorials on setting up a simple Django server, or you can have someone do it for you, for example: https://realpython.com/learn/start-django/

Comment: Hey MontyThreeCard, thanks for your help and detailed answer here! If you're interested in getting a Twilio shirt as a thank you, email mspeir@twilio.com.